# Page control directly switching

Tags: iphone

I have scroll view which contains 5 views and it include page control when i clicked over fourth bubble of page control it moves to second view but i want it should directly move to fourth view please help me to solve this problem.

calling of pageControl is as follows:

```
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageTurn:)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

implementation of pageTurn method is as follows:

```
- (void) pageTurn: (UIPageControl *) aPageControl
{
    int whichPage = aPageControl.currentPage;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320 * whichPage, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

and my scrollViewDidScroll is as follows:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) aScrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    pageControl.currentPage = offset.x /320 ;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the UIPageControl in the documentation, it says this:

> When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, the control sends the UIControlEventValueChanged event for handling by the delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the currentPage property to determine the page to display. **The page control advances only one page in either direction.**

The UIPageControl can only be used to switch one page at a time, hence it only changes to the second page when you click it (and not the fourth, no matter what dot you press).

You'll probably want to create custom UIButtons that make up your pagination control.